# Создание библиотеки

Tags: c++

Не получается подключить библиотеку с функциями. У меня должны быть: программа.cpp (в которой идет считывание входных данных) прототипы.h файл (там прототипы функций) и реализация функций в другом файле cpp.
Проблема только в подключении этих файлов. Читал что прототипы нужно подключить в программа.cpp вот так:

```
#include "прототипы.h"
```

А что далее делать не знаю.

Comment: А далее необходимо указать компилятору, чтобы он компилировал "другой файл cpp". И нужно сказать линкеру, чтобы он линковал программу с полученным объектником.

Answer (score -2):

Далее нужно сказать компилятору, что он так же должен компилировать библиотеку. Например, в Visual Studio для этого нужно щелкнуть правой кнопкой мышки на проекте, выбрать "Add->Existing Item..." (не знаю как перевели в русской версии, скорей всего что-то типа "Добавить->Существующий файл"). После чего компилятор будет знать, что нужно так же компилировать файл с библиотекой.
В Linux нужно так же скопировать файл с библиотекой в ту же папку и выполнять компиляцию примерно так"g++ программа.cpp библиотека.cpp".

Так же важно, чтобы компилятор знал, где искать заголовочный файл библиотеки. Самое простое, что можно сделать, это просто скопировать его к остальным исходникам (и в Visual studio так же включить в проект).